# Ruby regex to change old -> new Twitter image urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, url, twitter

When I sign up a user via Twitter, I pull their image url and store it in my DB as their profile pic. However, Twitter has changed the url of its images, which means the old urls I try to display like so....

```
<img src="<%= userlist.image_url %>">
```

...break.

I need a little regex to help me here. Here's what the old urls look like (offending bits in bold)....

http://**a0**.twimg.com/profile_images/3697684439/ddb8dbc04ac95f31100fff65b33326d6_**normal**.jpeg

and here's the new versions ...

http://**pbs**.twimg.com/profile_images/3697684439/ddb8dbc04ac95f31100fff65b33326d6_**bigger**.jpeg

In short, how do I do ..

```
<img src="<%= userlist.image_url.gsub(TURN "a0"->"pbs" AND "normal"->"bigger" please %>">
```

HELP ME PLEASE REGEX GODS! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
<img src="<%= userlist.image_url.sub('://a0','://pbs').sub('normal', 'bigger') %>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions arent even required. You can just use `gsub`

```
image_url.gsub("a0", "pbs").gsub("normal", "bigger")
```

Comment: This will replace *every* occurence of `a0` with `pbs` which could produce wrong urls. Furthermore, there is no need to use `gsub` over `sub` since you want to replace only the first occurence of each match.